# Arduino LCD Timer Display

Tags: c++, timer, arduino, lcd

I've been trying to make a timer with Arduino that will stop after 2 hours and make a buzzer go off. I've been succesful with getting the timer count seconds up, but now I've tried to make it display hours and minutes too & make buzzer go off, all help is appreciated, here is the code and [picture of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW0Rr.png):

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 
LiquidCrystal lcd(1,2,4,5,6,7); // setup the lcd 
#define button 3
         // setup integers //
int timerMode=0;
int buzzer=8;
int wait=400;
int longWait=5000;
int startTime;
int hours=(millis() - startTime) / 360000;




void setup() {
lcd.begin(16,2); // start lcd //
lcd.clear();  // clear old text //
pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP); // make button an input //
pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT); // make buzzer an output //
lcd.print("Ergo timer"); // print begin text //

 
}

void loop() {
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
if (digitalRead(button) == LOW){ // if button is pressed//
  startTime=millis();
  timerMode++;
  delay(wait);
}

if (timerMode==1){ // if timermode is 1 after a button press //
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Over 2 uur pause"); // print top text //
  lcd.setCursor(0,5);
  lcd.print( (millis() - startTime) / 1000); // print time in seconds //
  lcd.setCursor(0,4);
  lcd.print(":"); // print a column between //
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print( (millis() - startTime) / 60000); // print time in minutes //
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd. setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print( (millis() - startTime) / 360000); // print time in hours //
 

 }

  if (hours == 2){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("---Nu pause---");
    tone(buzzer,200,1000);
    
   }

if (timerMode > 1){
  delay(longWait);
  timerMode=0;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("---Ergo timer---");
 }
```

Comment: Since you are coding in C++, not C, then tag your question accordingly. Calling constructors isn't allowed in C.

Comment: What problem are you facing in the setup? Please be more clear about the question.

Comment: I am now able to count up seconds, I tried to format it to count up minutes and hours too but it just prints out a 0 on the second row instead, also when the timer finishes the finish texts is printed on the lcd, but the alarm buzzer doesnt go off. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`int hours=(millis() - startTime) / 360000;` is nonsense. C++ code is executed from top to bottom. The program doesn't magically re-visit previously executed lines whenever some variable changes.

Meaning that this line doesn't create some magical formula that will update `hours` whenever something changes. It just creates a single line of code which is executed once at start-up, when `startTime` is uninitialized and `millis()` might possibly just yield nonsense if the timer peripheral hardware isn't even set yet.

You need to move this code inside the main loop. Since this is an embedded system you should also drop all naive "primitive data types" like `int` in favour for `stdint.h`

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner, what do you mean by moving the code inside the main loop? Also could you link an article explaining what stdint.h is? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pileala On Arduino I believe `loop()` is the "main loop", called repeatedly. `stdint.h` should be mentioned in any decent C book. Or by typing "what is stdint.h" in your favourite search engine then click on the first thing that pops up.